# Configure Solr tokenizer to preserve original term using solr.PatternTokenizerFactory

Tags: solr, token, tokenize

My FQDN is [www.one.two.ac.uk](http://www.one.two.ac.uk) and I'd like to parse it such that one and two and one.two are searchable.  Here is what I've got so far: -

```
<fieldType name="hostfqdn" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s.]" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s.]" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This what the solr Analysis tab shows: -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiVZm.png)

So, as you see, I can break it down to individual token, but I've lost the original (combined). I'd like to also be able to search "one.two".

Comment: Wouldn't `one.two` as a query be split into `one` and `two` and thus match `one` and `two` on the index side?